# IE10 only displaying background gradients in quirks mode

Tags: background, internet-explorer-10, gradient

for some reason my body background gradients aren't showing up in IE10 except when the browswer is in quirks mode. IE9 and lower behave as expected. Code is below:

```
body {
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
background: rgb(252,254,252);
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(252,254,252,1) 20%, rgba(222,246,254,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(20%,rgba(252,254,252,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(222,246,254,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(252,254,252,1) 20%,rgba(222,246,254,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(252,254,252,1) 20%,rgba(222,246,254,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,254,252,1) 20%,rgba(222,246,254,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(252,254,252,1) 20%,rgba(222,246,254,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfefc', endColorstr='#def6fe',GradientType=1 );
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 }
```

The site is built using Zurb Foundation 4. Any help would be appreciated! I'm stumped.